# Stash static caching not ignoring POSTs like I think it should

Tags: stash, low-search, htaccess, caching

I am using Stash static caching (and it is AWESOME). I'm using Stash 2.4.5 and EE 2.7.2. I am also using Low Search 3.0.4.

So I have the `{exp:stash:static}` tag on my homepage, which is great. But if it's there (or, I should say, if my static_cache folder has a cached file for my homepage), my Low Search form doesn't work. When I submit a keyword search, it just loads the homepage.

The search works fine when I am logged in, presumably because I have Stash disabled for logged in users.

So, based on my .htaccess, I'd expect it to NOT load the homepage from the cache file because it's a POST.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong, or how to get this to work? I'd really like to keep my homepage static caching working.

In my .htaccess, I have

```
#################################################################################
# START MUSTASH STATIC CACHE RULES

# -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# default_site
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Exclude image files
RewriteCond $1 !\.(gif|jpe?g|png|ico)$ [NC]

# We only want GET requests
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} GET

# Exclude CSS/ACT EE URLs and 'preview'
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^(css|ACT|URL|preview)

# Uncomment this if you want to disable static caching for logged-in users
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !exp_sessionid [NC]

# Remove index.php from conditions
RewriteCond $1 ^(index.php/)*(.*)(/*)$

# Check if cached index.html exists
RewriteCond /path/to/my/public_html/static_cache/1/$2/index.html (.*\.(.*))$
RewriteCond %1 -f

# Rewrite to the cached page
RewriteRule ^(index.php/*)*(.*)(/*) /static_cache/1/$2/index.%2 [L]

# END MUSTASH STATIC CACHE RULES
#################################################################################
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally got this working (Low Search working with Stash static cached homepage)!!!

I added the following rule to my .htaccess, to get it to really really ignore POST requests. I'm not sure why this works (maybe it's my server environment? I'm on a Nexcess EE-Optimized plan).

So I added the following RewriteCond

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET)
```

And now, my Low Search form works and I can keep my homepage static-cached!

Answer (score 1):

Your htaccess looks OK to me--I think it should be doing what you want. But you could try changing the Request Method match from this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} GET
```

to this more strict match:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^GET$
```

Another rewrite technique I've used, that I know works, is to enclose the rules in a `Limit` block, like:

```
<Limit GET>
   # your caching rewrite rules here
</Limit>
```

Comment: Hi Jay. Thanks for your suggestion. I've tried both of those things, and neither did the trick :( BUT, I did finally get it working! See my answer below.